# How can I run servlet without user interacting

Tags: java, servlets, contextpath

I want to excute a servlet to get server name,server port and ContextPath from request.
But I don't want to invoke servlet by user interacting. I want excute this servlet by Java code.
I'm not sure it's possible.
Please give me recommendation.

Comment: What do you mean by run?  Instantiate a servlet or actually hit one of the doX methods?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: To make a request you already need the URL, port, etc.  What is the functionality you are trying to achieve here?  There'll be a way to achieve it I'm sure but not with the mechanism you're suggesting.

Comment: Pulled the spring tag off this, since it has nothing to do with spring.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just simply make use of [URL](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to request the servlet.

For more sophisticated use try [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

Comment: If that's what Chan is trying to do, I think the question would be what makes 'use of the URL' and then opens up the question of what should the parameters be for such a request.

Comment: Yeah, even I tried to guess it intelligently. The first part is still not clear to me, I mean "..to get server name etc..".

Comment: So essentially to make a request to a servlet to start it without making a request, you are making a request :)

Comment: Thats what he asked, how on earth I will know if he really means something like load-on-startup. :)

Comment: Hey Vinegar - agreed, anything that invokes the servlet will, by definition, already know the URL, port, etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you just want to execute some code to extract information from the request, why are you trying to invoke a servlet? Just write a method somewhere, and call it.

You could also use a Servlet Filter to extract this info on every request, add the results to the HttpServletRequest object as an attribute, so that any other servlets that process the request can find it and use it.

If you mean you want to make the servlet load at startup, you can add this within the web.xml configuration:

```
<servlet>
  ...
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your servlet is doing something like calling a service every x minutes without a user interaction then you probably want to do something different.

You can use a `ServletContextListener` to listen to when the web context is started and to then start whatever code you want.

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

Comment: You guessed too, isn't it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers
Actually, my problem is : I have an web application and a WebService (on diferent server).
I want web application invoke webservice (after specific duration) to send data (domain, port,context path..) to webservice so that I can know where my web application is deployed.

To solve this problem I have created a servlet to call WebService and by using this servlet I have HttpServletRequest object and I can get domain, port, context path.Then I can send data to webservice.
But I don't know how to execute this servlet(after specific duration) without user interaction